# In Application Insights dependency tracking, how to set Dependency Type and Result Code?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-application-insights

When tracking dependencies with Application Insights, in Azure Portal these events contain properties *Dependency Type* and *Result code* that are unset.

[image: Dependency Properties in Microsoft Azure]

How to track dependencies so that properties *Dependency type* and *Result code* are set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please upgrade to use the latest prerelease .NET SDK Nuget:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web/2.0.0-rc1

Just tried a simple example:

```
DependencyTelemetry dep = new DependencyTelemetry("DepName", "CommandName", DateTimeOffset.Now.AddSeconds(-1), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), true);
dep.DependencyTypeName = "MyTypeName";
dep.ResultCode = "200";

new TelemetryClient(new TelemetryConfiguration()
{
                InstrumentationKey = "ikey",
                TelemetryChannel = new InMemoryChannel()
 }).TrackDependency(dep);
```

and I can see ResultCode and Type:
[image]